# How does saying "pasim" help us safely enunciate the name of Hashem?

Tags: shemos-sacred-names, yosef, birchas-kohanim

I'm reading an article about the [*kesones pasim* and *birchas kohanim* here](http://havolim.blogspot.ca/2007/11/vayeishev-breishis-373.html), and one paragraph had me confused. The article is discussing the portion of the *yehi ratzon* in which we ask Hashem to act like Yaakov did when giving the *kesones pasim*. The Hebrew text reads

> ויהיו דברי נשמעים לעבודתך כשם שנתת את יוסף צדיק בשעה שהלבישו אביו כתונת פסים לחן ולחסד ולרחמים...

The confusing paragraph is in the article:

> Of course, the main reason we refer to the story of the kesones pasim is because saying 'pasim' enables us to safely enunciate the letters of the Sheim Hashem that is in Birchas Kohanim. But it does also have to make sense, and certainly we would not ask for something that resulted in such suffering.

How does referring to the story of the pasim "enable us to safely enunciate the letters of the Sheim Hashem" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you open for example the Artscroll siddur (in my case p. 698 of the Ashkenaz-English version), you'll see that there's a 22 letter Divine Name hidden in it that is not read, but just scanned with the eyes. The cited verses contain the letters of this name in the proper order, and by reading them you'll pronounce them correctly. פסים is a part of this name, hence it is cited.